# NoClassDefFoundError: FixedStepPhysicsWorld

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm developing a simple game with AndEngine and I wanted to put some walls on the screen so that the character I move has to go around and stuffs like that.

I found out that I need a `FixedStepPhysicsWorld` object for this simple task. I downloaded the latest version of both `AndEngine` and `AndEnginePhysics2DExtension` from GitHub. My game works fine until I call

`this.mPhysicsWorld = new FixedStepPhysicsWorld(30, new Vector2(0, 0), false, 8, 1);`

I get get the following error:

```
03-28 23:04:57.713: E/AndEngine(16548): PacManActivity.onCreateScene failed. @(Thread: 'GLThread 15')
03-28 23:04:57.713: E/AndEngine(16548): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.FixedStepPhysicsWorld
03-28 23:04:57.713: E/AndEngine(16548):     at com.rokuum.games.android.pacman.activity.PacManActivity.onCreateScene(PacManActivity.java:208)
03-28 23:04:57.713: E/AndEngine(16548):     at org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity.onCreateScene(SimpleBaseGameActivity.java:48)
03-28 23:04:57.713: E/AndEngine(16548):     at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$3.onCreateResourcesFinished(BaseGameActivity.java:167)
03-28 23:04:57.713: E/AndEngine(16548):     at org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity.onCreateResources(SimpleBaseGameActivity.java:43)
03-28 23:04:57.713: E/AndEngine(16548):     at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreateGame(BaseGameActivity.java:179)
03-28 23:04:57.713: E/AndEngine(16548):     at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated(BaseGameActivity.java:108)
03-28 23:04:57.713: E/AndEngine(16548):     at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(EngineRenderer.java:59)
03-28 23:04:57.713: E/AndEngine(16548):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1349)
03-28 23:04:57.713: E/AndEngine(16548):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1119)
```

Both AndEngine and the extension is added to the build path (as .jar files) and the game builds and compiles without any errors. Also both jar files marked az exported in the "Order and Export" tab of "Java Build Path" window.

I'm googling about this issue for like a day now and I'm getting really lost. IMHO it has nothing to do with AndEngine or Android or whatsoever but rather a misconfiguration or something.

Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a `Caused by:` in the stack trace that you haven't posted?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. You should copy "armeabi"-"armeabi-v7a"-"x86" folders from "AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension" folder's "libs" folder to your game's "libs" folder. It  will solve your problem.

Comment: I copied files and defined libs folder as a sources folder and then worked for me thnx!

Answer (score 0):

If the minSdkVersion is less than the API level you are compiling with, Android will let you compile with no errors, but throw a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError if you try and run on a device that does not support that function in its API level. I've gotten that error before when I used an API level 9 function call (i.e. Android 2.3) on a 2.2 phone. It is possible that AndEngine is doing the same thing.